# Hyperbolic Nature of Special Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, geometry

Here is two facts about the "hyperbolic nature" of SR:

1. It's well known that a *special Lorentz transformation* of speed $v$ can be written in terms of the *rapidity* $\xi$ ($v=\tanh\xi$). Thus a spatial Lorentz transformation can be seen as a **hyperbolic rotation**.
2. The set of all events that are at the same distance (spacetime interval) from one point (say the origin) forms **hyperboloïds** (with one or two sheets, depending of the nature of the sign of the spacetime interval)

As I understand it, all this comes from the fact that Minkowski's pseudo-metric is hyperbolic.

Is there more two interpret? Is there more links with hyperbolic geometry?

Comment: You might find the [Ehrenfest Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox) interesting, if you don't know about it already.

Comment: You can look for Rindler Metric. This would explain the second fact clearly.